# How to tease access control content to non-authenticated users

Tags: views, users

I have member only content and using Roles and Access Control to serve it up. The goal is to display member only content in a view block to non-authenticated users so they would click on it but be forced to either login or signup. Similar to how some online publications posts content but then have more to offer after you subscribe or pay for membership.

I was trying to do this with the role permissions on views but I think I'm missing a simple config.

Comment: Disable sql rewriting in the view and go to town displaying your content.